# NSTextView overlay causes oddities with first responder status

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, first-responder

I have an `NSTextView` in an `NSScrollView`, and I am programmatically inserting an `NSView` subclass as a subview of the `NSTextView`.  This `NSView` acts as an overlay, superimposing graphical information about the text beneath it.

I thought it was working quite well until I noticed that the text view does not respond to right clicks.  Other operations (editing, selection) seem to work just fine.

Also, if the first responder is changed to a sibling of the scroll view (an outline view, for example) the text view does not regain first responder status from clicking on it.  The selection will change in response to clicking, but the selection highlight is gray instead of blue (indicating that the text view is not the first responder).

If I offset the frame of the overlay subview, the text view behaves 100% normally in the area not overlapped by the overlay, but the overlapped area behaves incorrectly, as outlined above.

**Steps To Replicate This Behavior on Mac OS X 10.6.4:**

1. Create a plain old non-document-based Cocoa app.
2. Add an `NSTextView' IBOutlet to the app delegate .h.
3. Add an `NSTextView` to the window in MainMenu.xib.  Connect the textView outlet.
4. Type in a bit of code:

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
NSView *overlay = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:textView.bounds];
[textView addSubview:overlay];
[overlay release];
```

Run the app, observe that right click in the text area does not work as it should, yet you can still otherwise interact with the text view.

Next, add an NSOutlineView to the window in the xib.  Observe that once focus leaves the text area (if you click on the outline view) with the overlay in place, you cannot set the focus back to the text view (it will not become first responder again).

---

Is there some way I can enable the `NSTextView` to receive all of its events, even though my `NSView` overlay does not accept first responder or mouse events?  I suspect this might be related to the field editor – perhaps it is ignoring events it thinks are destined to the overlay view?

Comment: More context (and likely code) is needed.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what you view as missing?

Comment: Turns out it's very simple to replicate in an app built from scratch.  I've added steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make your overlay an instance of a custom view class that forwards all events and accessibility messages to the text view. You may also need to convert any view-relative coordinates to the text view's coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with it, but another possibility would be to use a Core Animation layer as an overlay.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, however I'm specifically interested in responding to mouse events and would prefer not to reinvent the wheel with respect to mapping them to sublayers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to handle this is by making your overlay view a custom subclass of NSView, and then overriding the **hitTest:** method to always return *nil*. This will prevent the overlay view from participating in the responder chain. Instead, events will get sent automatically to it's superview or views higher up the view hierarchy. You might also want to override **acceptsFirstResponder** to return *NO* to be safe (in case it's accidentally set programatically).